# Resizing JScrollPane based on JDialog size

Tags: java, swing, resize, components, jscrollpane

I have a resizable JDialog and 4 big components inside:

1. a JLabel on the top left;
2. a JTable on the left;
3. a fixed JPanel on the top;
4. a JScrollPane with a JPanel in a GridLayout inside it. JScrollPane has a Horizontal and Vertical ScrollBar policy AS_NEEDED.

I would like to keep the first three components aligned to the Scrollable JPanel, like a JTable behaviour. So I need to eventually scroll that JPanel when the parent JDialog is resized. Is that possible?

If I resize the JDialog the ScrollPane remain fixed in its position and doesn't automatically resize.

How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: Possible. If you can share the code, it can be adapted.

Comment: I'm using the NetBeans GUI builder, but I just find out that GroupLayout maybe useful in this situation. I have to try.